# Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: File store path does not exist and can not be created

Tags: moodle

I installed auth_emailadmin_moodle plugin in Moodle. After installation, I purged cached. And then white page appears. After debugging, appears as below.

> Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: File store path does not exist and can not be created.
>   Blockquote

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the location of the stored web content, Moodle needs a data directory that is writable by the web server.

Look inside the 'config.php' file which should be located in the root web directory of your Moodle installation.

You should see a line that looks like this:

```
$CFG->dataroot  = '/home/moodle/moodledata'
```

Your file path is probably something different - this is just where I store mine. Make sure whatever directory is listed there exists and can be written to by the account that runs your web server.

You can read more about this directory here: https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_the_.28moodledata.29_data_directory

I'm not 100% sure this is the fix for your problem, but it is a good place to start.

Good luck, and have fun with Moodle!

Comment: Thank you for your discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error while upgrading the moodle and power gets cut. 
Do one thing to resolve this error, **Delete** 'cache' folder from **moodledata** folder and create a new folder with name 'cache' and hit refresh.

After loading, hit 'localhost/admin/purgecaches.php' on the browser and click "Purge all caches" button.

CHEERS